# MYSQL use a value from a table for the Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, subquery

can someone help me with the query I need. I looked already for hours but I do not get it.

So here is the thing....

I have 3 tables

Table 1 event

```
-----------------------------------------
| ID | name | date | seats | ... |
-----------------------------------------
| 1 | name1 | 01/01 | 50 | ... |
| 2 | name2 | 02/02 | 60 | ... |
| 3 | name3 | 03/03 | 55 | ... |
| 4 | name4 | 04/04 | 40 | ... |
| 5 | name5 | 05/05 | 100 | ... |
| 6 | name6 | 06/06 | 20 | ... |
-----------------------------------------
```

Table 2 person

```
-----------------
| ID | person|
-----------------
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 4 | name4 |
| 5 | name5 |
| 6 | name6 |
-----------------
```

Table 3 reservation

```
---------------------------------
| ID | idperson |idevent|
---------------------------------
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | 3 |
---------------------------------
```

So here my Question:

When I offer a Person the events I want to make sure, that there are still empty seats.So I need to count the idevent from reservation and check if the number of seats in event is allready reached. At the end I want to have a List with all the available events which the person has not booked yet.

How do have to write the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the end I want to have a List with all the available events which the person has not booked yet.

Here is one approach using correlated subqueries:

```
select e.*
from events e
where 
    not exists (select 1 from reservation r where r.idevent = e.idevent and r.idperson = ?)
    and (select count(*) from reservation r where r.idevent = e.idevent) < e.seats
```

The question mark represents the id of the person for which you want to show the reporting.

The first subquery filters out events that the person already booked, and the second one ensures that there are still seats available.

You can shorten the query by using a single subquery for filtering, although it is makes the query a bit harder to follow:

```
select e.*
from events e
where not exists (
    select 1
    from reservation
    where r.idevent = e.idevent
    group by r.idevent
    having count(*) = e.seats or max(r.idperson = e.idperson) = 1
)
```